# How to configure screen-restore in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, xterm

Depending on the terminal/environment following sequence has different effects:

```
$ ls
1
2
$ man ls
enter q
```

Either I see last displayed man-page screen above the current prompt or the ls output and previous shell output is restored. Same effect is observed e.g. when using `vim` and then suspending it to do something on the shell.

On Fedora 19 - the default of screen seems to be no-restore, a gnome-terminal/xterm uses do-restore by default.

On Solaris it depends on the used terminal/terminfo db it seems.

I want to configure the restore behavior consistently between different systems/terminals.

Comment: If you always run GNU screen, you will get consistent behavior.

Answer (score 22):

The feature seems to be called 'alternate screen' or switching between normal and alternate screen.

You can explore it using an xterm. For example type `man man` in an `xterm` and exit man. Now you can switch to the alternate screen via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mouse2 (middle click) -> 'Show alternate screen'. Alternatively you can directly enter the [xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), e.g.:

```
$ echo -e '\033[?47h' # alternate screen
$ echo -e '\033[?47l' # normal screen
```

The last two commands also work in gnome-terminal (probably in others, too).

What happens when `man`/`vi`/`less` etc. startup is basically they send an abstract clear-screen command. On exit (or suspend) they send an abstract restore-screen command. How the command translates to concrete terminal control sequences is defined in the [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database.

### Disable alternate screen switching

What should work for all terminals is to adjust local terminfo entries, i.e. removing the mapping of abstract clear/restore screen commands.

You can do it like this - for the current `$TERM` entry (for gnome-terminal on Fedora 19 for example):

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ infocmp -1 > xterm-256color
$ sed 's/^\(xterm-256color\)|/\1-na|/ ; /smcup\|rmcup/d ' \
    xterm-256color > xterm-256color-na
$ diff -u xterm-256color* 
--- xterm-256color  2013-08-04 16:33:52.041393461 +0200
+++ xterm-256color-na   2013-08-04 16:36:56.829930520 +0200
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 #  Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
-xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors,
+xterm-256color-na|xterm with 256 colors,
    am,
    bce,
    ccc,
@@ -155,7 +155,6 @@
    rin=\E[%p1%dT,
    rmacs=\E(B,
    rmam=\E[?7l,
-   rmcup=\E[?1049l,
    rmir=\E[4l,
    rmkx=\E[?1l\E>,
    rmm=\E[?1034l,
@@ -170,7 +169,6 @@
    sgr0=\E(B\E[m,
    smacs=\E(0,
    smam=\E[?7h,
-   smcup=\E[?1049h,
    smir=\E[4h,
    smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
    smm=\E[?1034h,
$ tic xterm-256color-na # loads the file to $HOME/.terminfo
$ find ~/.terminfo -type f
$ HOME/.terminfo/x/xterm-256color-na
```

Now you can test it via:

```
$ TERM=xterm-256color-na man man # and then hit q
```

You can repeat the above steps for other terminals if you use multiple ones. If everything works as expected you can set `TERM` via your shell rc-file.

You can also directly specify the terminal name as a parameter to `infocmp`, e.g.:

```
$ infocmp -1 screen > screen
```

### Enable alternate screen switching

Some terminals support the alternate screen switching feature (e.g. [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html)), but [disable it by default](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Redisplay.html#index-altscreen-123).

For `screen` you can enable it via your `~/.screenrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.screenrc
altscreen
```

If you remote login via ssh to - say - a Solaris system perhaps the remotely configured system-wide terminfo-database is kind-of historic, broken or includes some unusual/Solaris-specific defaults that don't match the 'bleeding edge' terminals you run ssh in.

Thus, it is an option to just copy the local terminfo database from /usr/share/info (on the client) to `host:~/.terminfo` (on the server).

In case the compiled terminfo format is not compatible you can also export/import the entries like in the previous paragraph.

I've tried in with a terminfo-db from a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installation and copying it directly to a Solaris 10 system worked.

In case you want to share an alternative terminfo db between users you specify its path via the `TERMINFO` environment variable.

### Ignore the Control Sequence

Some terminals support disabling the control sequence for alternate screen switching. For example xterm has an option, gnome-terminal has not.

For xterm it is the [X-ressource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources), e.g.

```
XTerm*titeInhibit: true
```

### Program specific configurations

Some programs have configuration files to configure what control sequence/terminfo commands they send. For example

```
$ LESS=X less foo
```

configures `less` to not clear/restore the screen.

For `vim` you can include something like

```
set t_ti= t_te=
```

in you `~/.vimrc`.

I haven't found on option how to configure that behavior for top - by default it does not send restore-screen.

Comment: The sed cmd actually delete the whole line containing `smcup` or `rmcup`. In my case, there are other stuffs coming on the same line with them. Those other stuffs also got deleted. So maybe something like `s/[sr]mcup=[^,]*,//'` is better.