# Remnants of previously closed file displayed in terminal

Tags: terminal

On several Unix servers, I have seen below behavior:

- I list all the files using `ls -lrt`: 3 files are being shown up
- I open one of the files using vi editor
- I close the open file

Now in some Unix system, I can still see the earlier screen as it is as in point 2 (listing those 3 files, `ls -lrt` output as it is) whereas on some systems, the text of recently opened file is printed.

I want to know which setting in profile or some `*rc` file this behavior depends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like the [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) *alternate screen* feature (implemented in most terminal emulators which have some similarity to xterm, including rxvt).

xterm maintains its output window in three parts:

- the *normal* screen, as large as the window,
- the *scrollback*, to which lines are copied as the window becomes full, and
- the *alternate* screen, to which xterm can switch to/from when displaying "full-screen" programs.

The switching is done using an escape sequence.  By convention, that *may* be part of the terminal description's initialization (and ending) capabilities: termcap `ti` and `te` or terminfo `smcup` and `rmcup`.  This is a convention (neither termcap nor terminfo have a special capability for this feature), and since some users do, while others do not want it, the terminal descriptions differ.

Further reading:

- *[Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)* (xterm FAQ)
- [Types of library users](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) (ncurses FAQ)

Assorted advice (not all good, either way):

- [screen: how to turn on alternate screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868652/screen-how-to-turn-on-alternate-screen)
- [How to configure screen-restore in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/how-to-configure-screen-restore-in-a-terminal)
- [Exorcising the Evil Alternate Screen](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html)
- [Fixing the alternate screen problem](http://blogmal.42.org/tidbits/titeinhibit.story)

Comment: thanks Thomas.I will go through the links you have shared to get a better clarity !!!